# Slicing complex dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to be able to print out just a single character from this dictionary but I haven't been able to figure out the syntax or find it anywhere.  Is there a way to do this in vanilla Python 2.7.x given the code below?

```
dct = {"c":[["1","1","0"],["0","0","0"]], "d":[["1","1","0"],["1","0","0"]],}
for x in dct:
    print [x][0][0]
```

I want the output to be: 11

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you want the first value of the first sub-list of each of the value lists.  Do you care what order they come out in?  Iterating over the entries in a dict doesn't guarantee order.

Comment: maybe something like `for x in dct.keys(): print ''.join(dct[x][0][0:2])`, but I'm not sure which indices in the values you are getting the `1`s from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x in dct:
    print(dct[x][0][0])
```

Comment: Of course, duh!  Thank you!